# matrix multiplied by rotation matrix on right side and transpose(rotation) on left side

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Would a matrix remain un-rotated if it is multiplied by an orthonormal rotation matrix on right side and transpose of same rotation matrix on the left side?

Comment: The meaning of 'remain unrotated' is not clear apropos of a matrix.   What you describe as multiplying on one side by an orthonormal rotation matrix and on the other side by its transpose (also its inverse) produces a *similarity* transformation.

Comment: oh, I actually wasn't familiar with the similarity transformation.

Comment: The key fact to know about similar matrices is that they share the same eigenvalues and related properties (such as their characteristic and minimal polynomials).  However the similarity transformation can change the eigenvectors corresponding to those eigenvalues.  In fact we often make use of *orthogonal similarity transformations* to change a real symmetric matrix into a real diagonal matrix (whose eigenvalues and eigenvectors are "found by inspection").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @hardmath suggested, by doing what you say you'd get a similarity transformation: suppose that you have a matrix $A$ and an invertible matrix $P$. Then, the matrix $B = P^{-1}AP$ is said to be *similar* to A.

And here's a counterexample. Suppose that you have the Rotation matrix

$R = \begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}          \\[0.3em]
       -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}            \\[0.3em] 
     \end{bmatrix}$

and its inverse (transpose)

$R^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}          \\[0.3em]
       \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}            \\[0.3em] 
     \end{bmatrix}$

Then, if you consider a matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1          \\[0.3em]
       1 & 0            \\[0.3em] 
     \end{bmatrix}$

and you left-multiply it by $R^{-1}$ and right-multiply it by $R$, you get

$\begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(-2+\sqrt{3}) & \frac{1}{4}(2+\sqrt{3})          \\[0.3em]
       \frac{1}{4}(-1+\sqrt{3}(1+\sqrt{3})) & \frac{1}{4}(1+ 2\sqrt{3})            \\[0.3em] 
     \end{bmatrix}$

which is clearly a completely different matrix!

Comment: So, what exactly it means for two matrix to be similar?

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are said similar if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $B$ = $P^{-1}AP$

Comment: Matrix $A$ and matrix $B$ are said to be similar iff there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}BP$.  They are said to be *orthogonally similar* when $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e. when $P^{-1}=P^T$.

Comment: So it is orthogonally similar, which we want? But what else does similarity mean (physically/intuitively) if the elements don't have to be the same?

Comment: @IsamAbdullah: You should look into the topic of change of basis and matrix representations of linear transformations.  Saying two matrices are similar amounts to them being two representations of the same linear transformation with respect to (possibly) different ordered bases.